# Independence of random variables in a Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $\{B(t):t \geq 0\}$ be a standard one-dimensional Brownian motion. How do we prove that $B(12)-B(10)$ is independent of $(B(3),B(5))$?

I can see that $B(12)-B(10)$ is independent of $B(5)$, and $B(12)-B(10)$ is independent of $B(3)$. But that doesn't imply that $B(12)-B(10)$ is independent of $(B(3),B(5))$.

Also, $B(3), B(5)$ aren't independent, so $B(3), B(5), B(12)-B(10)$ aren't mutually independent either.

Motivation: To prove that for a fixed $s>0$, the stochastic process $\{B(t+s)-B(s):t\geq 0\}$ is independent of the process $\{B(t): 0 \leq t \leq s\}$

Comment: Hint 1: $B(3)$ and $B(5)$ are special cases of $B(3)-B(0)$ and $B(5)-B(0)$ -assuming $B(0)\equiv 0$. Hint 2. No one claims that $B(3)$ and $B(5)$ need to be independent for your final result to hold.

Comment: @KurtG., I can see that both these hints are true. I don't see how it helps. That is, how do we show that $Pr[B(12)-B(10)=a, B(5)=b, B(3)=c] = Pr[B(12)-B(10)=a]*Pr[B(5)=b, B(3)=c]$

Comment: Hint 3. Can you show that $B(t+s)-B(s)$ is independent of every $B(r)$ with $r\le s$?

Comment: @KurtG., I can show that for a single $r$, not for all $r \leq s$. This is true because $B(t+s)-B(s),B(s)-B(r),B(r)-B(0)$ are independent.

Comment: You can show it for every single $r\le s$. That's all you need since the $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal F}^B_s$ is generated by $B(r)$ with $r\le s\,.$

Comment: How do we prove that $B(t+s)-B(s)$ is independent of $(B(r):0 \leq r \leq s )$? This is my question.

Answer (score 1):

- For each $n\in N$ and any $r_1\le ...\le r_n\le s$ and any $a_i\le b_i$ the event
  $$\tag{1}
  \Big\{B(r_1)\in (a_1,b_1),B(r_2)-B(r_1)\in (a_1,b_1),...,B(r_n)-B(r_{n-1})\in (a_n,b_n)\Big\}
  $$
  is independent of $B(t+s)-B(s)\,.$ The intersection of two events of the form (1) is again of that form. In other words, those events form a [$\pi$-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system). Consequently, the independence
  [carries over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system#Independent_random_variables) to the entire $\sigma$-algebra that is generated by the events of the
  form (1).
- The $\sigma$-algebra above is $\sigma(B(r);r\le s)\,.$

*Proof*. For each $n\in N$ and any $r_1\le ...\le r_n\le s$ we have obviously
$$\tag{2}
\sigma\Big(B(r_1),B(r_2)-B(r_1),...,B(r_n)-B(r_{n-1})\Big)=\sigma\Big(
B(r_1),B(r_2),...,B(r_n)\Big)\,.
$$
The $\sigma$-algebra generated by all events of the form (1) is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all $\sigma$-algebras on the LHS of (2) (when $n$ runs through $\mathbb N$ and $r_1\le...\le r_n\le s$ run through all those possible values). Therefore it is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all $\sigma$-algebras on the RHS of (2) which is nothing else than the definition of $\sigma(B(r);r\le s)\,.$ $\quad\quad\Box$

Comment: Hello @KurtG., I think OP will benefit from a little more detail on the last claim about the family of sets generating $\sigma(B_s,r\leq s)$

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see why "For each $n \in N$ and any $r_1 < ...< r_n \leq s$ and any $a_i < b_i$ the event $\{B(r_1)\in(a_1,b_1),...,B(r_n) \in (a_n,b_n)\}$ is independent of $B(t+s)-B(s)$" is true. Also, what do you mean when you say an event A is independent of a random variable X? Is it : for all $B \in \sigma(X)$, $Pr[A,B]=Pr[A]Pr[B]$?

Comment: @lively_radish Tried to address this comment in the last edit. Yes to your last question. I cannot help thinking that you may want to study in detail a book such as Heinz Bauer, *Probability Theory*.